# Как победить кодировку в django debugger

Tags: python, django, postgresql, отладка, pgadmin4

В общем, проблема в том что я не могу ничего поменять в админ панеле django, а дебагер показывает мне проблему, где русские символы заменены заменяющими символами, и чтоб узнать получше проблему мне надо победить кодировку, вот код, хотя он особо не нужен:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/goods/products/12/change/
```

������������: INSERT ������ UPDATE �� �������������� "django_admin_log" ���������������� ���������������������� ���������������� ���������� "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL: �������� (user_id)=(4) ���������������������� �� �������������� "auth_user".

Comment: победите кодировку в консоли/терминале куда дебагер выводит свою информацию.